# Corsair HyperX Alpha Cloud Wireless Headset (Release date: Feb 2022) BRICKED (Doesn't work, does not respond)

Tags: headset, wireless-headset

### **SITUATION.**

My Corsair HyperX Alpha Cloud Wireless Headset (2022) kind of bricked and went unresponsive. Last voice-prompt (as power indicator) that I heard from the headset was "battery level at 50%"--this headset should be notorious for those voice-prompts though it will truly be a legendary product because its fantastic spec and intended robustness (other than bricking before the warranty period ends, oc). Anyways, I went out of range (which happens often despite not going passed the claimed 20 metre range). Maybe, there was some interference or EMF in the area too. Then, POOF! the headset no longer played music when I got back within the effective range. It did not respond to holding the power button. No voice prompts were triggered when you quick-press the power button. When I went to the computer to fiddle with the volume wheel, the computer audio settings did not respond as it usually would when you rolled the wheel (on the right ear cup). Holding the power button didn't fix it either. Tried to charge it a bit, thinking maybe the battery was failing (which is worse), but that didn't do anything.

***So, it is officially a BRICK.***

### Side Note Details to Further Outline the Problem.

Also, side note: Started to notice the battery drain a little faster despite only having charged it 4-5 times ever (since the battery was so amazing on this product). Not sure if its because of extended use at higher volumes, but when it worked, it still charged quite fast and lasts for a solid 1-4 months on a full charge.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

***6 EASY STEPS:***

1. Downloaded HyperX Cloud Alpha Wireless Firmware Update (even if I already did the firmware update. The idea here is to flash the bad memory. Here's the link: https://support.hyperx.com/Headsets/Cloud-Alpha-Wireless/2708994151/Cloud-Alpha-Wireless-Firmware-Update-3107-4107.htm)
2. Plug headset to PC via USB-C
3. Keep USB wirlesss reciever/dongle connected to PC
4. Unzip file and follow instructions (hit next next next)
5. Wait for Firmware flash executable to do its thing. DO NOT UNPLUG ANYTHING!
6. When the window prompt tells you its done, press the power button!

***VOILA!***

It should work now (which you can tell when you hear the semi-annoying voice-prompt guy (who grows on you). He's alive! :D)

Happy camper again. HyperX Customer Service, take note :P.